# Cosmosdb documentdb Sql query with params returns 0 items

Tags: c#, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with a query. When I pass a single parameter (deviceId) the query works normally. If I add the other two parameters, no items are returned to me even though the collections are correctly populated and have items that satisfy the required conditions.
I enclose the code c # which does the above described.

```
 public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsCompact(string deviceId,DateTime startdate,DateTime enddate)
        {
            string collectionToUse;
            SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec = new SqlQuerySpec();

            if (typeof(T).ToString().IndexOf("Telemetry") != -1)
            {
                DocumentDBRepository<EBB.Web.Telemerty.Models.CosmosDBTelemetry>.Initialize();
                collectionToUse = AppSettings.Collection;

                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText = "SELECT c.messageUID as messageUID, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.deviceId as deviceId, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_VIn(c.VIn) as VIn, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_AIn(c.AIn) as AIn, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_W(c.W) as W, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_Var(c.Var) as Var, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "from Telemetry c ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "where c.deviceId = @deviceId and ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.EventProcessedUtcTime >= @startdate and ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.EventProcessedUtcTime <= @enddate";
                sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                    {
                          new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId),
                          new SqlParameter("@startdate",startdate),
                          new SqlParameter("@enddate",enddate)
                    };

            }
            else
            {
                DocumentDBRepository<EBB.Web.Telemerty.Models.CosmosDBEvents>.Initialize();
                collectionToUse = AppSettings.Collection2;
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText = "select doc.uid as uid, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.deviceId as deviceId, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.eventId as eventId, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.ts as ts, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.startTS as startTS, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.endTS as endTS, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.no as no, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.params as params, ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.tags as tags ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "from Events doc ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "where doc.deviceId = @deviceId and ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.EventProcessedUtcTime >= @startdate and ";
                sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.EventProcessedUtcTime <= @enddate";
                sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                    {
                          new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId),
                          new SqlParameter("@startdate",startdate),
                          new SqlParameter("@enddate",enddate)
                    };
            }

            FeedOptions opt = new FeedOptions
            {
                EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                MaxItemCount = -1
            };

            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(AppSettings.Database, collectionToUse), sqlQuerySpec,
                    opt).AsDocumentQuery();

            List<T> results = new List<T>();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
         }
```

query.toSting() in Telemetry case is equal to :

```
    "{\"query\":\"SELECT c.messageUID as messageUID, c.deviceId as deviceId, udf.UDF_VIn(c.VIn) as VIn, udf.UDF_AIn(c.AIn) as AIn, udf.UDF_W(c.W) as W, udf.UDF_Var(c.Var) as Var, c.EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime from Telemetry c where c.deviceId = @deviceId and c.EventProcessedUtcTime >= @startdate and c.EventProcessedUtcTime <= @enddate\",\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"@deviceId\",\"value\":\"where c.deviceId = \\\"EBBBrain1874008291\\\"\"},{\"name\":\"@startdate\",\"value\":\"2019-06-01T00:00:00\"},{\"name\":\"@enddate\",\"value\":\"2019-06-30T00:00:00\"}]}"
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance. Simone

Comment: Is the parameter that's working the `deviceId` and the dates are failing?

Comment: @Nick : yes the date are failing and deviceId is working.

Comment: Can you please make a `query.ToString()` call after your `CreateDocumentQuery` line? This will show us how your query is formed and executed. I'm suspecting there is a serialization inconsistency

Comment: @NIck : I put in the post query.ToString() result.

Comment: Ok and now can you show us some example of the `EventProcessedUtcTime` field in the database?

Comment: @NIck : It looks like the query is being translated badly.

Comment: @Nick :  "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2019-05-31T14:58:15.3238226Z

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because of the serialization of the property in the parameters. When you're creating the document you are using UTC but when you're querying, the SDK thinks the `DateTimeKind` of the `DateTime` is `Unspecified` (which is valid) so it's converting it in this unspecified  format `2019-06-30T00:00:00` instead of this UTC `2019-05-31T14:58:15.3238226Z` one. If you used something like `DateTime.Now` it would use the local format which looks like this `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00`. The reason why you don't get any results back is because the date range check is ultimately a string comparison which is enabled by the ISO formatting.

To get that working you need need to use the `DateTime.SpecifyKind` method. Here is how you parameters clause should look like:

```
sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
{
      new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId),
      new SqlParameter("@startdate", DateTime.SpecifyKind(startdate, DateTimeKind.Utc)),
      new SqlParameter("@enddate", DateTime.SpecifyKind(enddate, DateTimeKind.Utc))
};
```

Comment: Using the notation you suggest me I have the same result. Zero items returned

Comment: Can you check what the final query looks like?

Comment: I add it to your post

Comment: Furthermore, the instruction  **deviceId.ToString("")**  generates an exception because the empty string in brackets is not accepted.

Comment: @SimoneSpagna Sorry i accidentally added the tostring thing. I tested the code as pasted here and it worked fine.

Comment: It's the one in my answer